# Move captions under gallery images in twenty fourteen theme

Tags: functions, gallery, thumbnails, captions

The new twenty fourteen theme will only show captions on top of gallery thumbs. Is there something I can do in the functions (or copy from twenty ten) to make them visible all the time and show up under the thumbnail, like they did/do in twenty ten? I saw this question on the WP forums but no one has answered it.

This is how they show up in 2010 [2010 captions on thumbs](http://larkboutique.net/summer-2013/)

And this is how they work now[2014 captions](http://emgraphics.net/rawanda/rwamagana-lutheran-school/student-life/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by ripping out all the css for sectio  5.4 Galleries (anything under .galleries) and slapping in the code from the twenty ten theme.  Needed a bit of tweaking, but they are now showing properly.